# Fluent API of a Role based access control implementation

Tags: c#, security, authorization

I am trying to provide a fluent API for authorization [based on roles](http://profsandhu.com/journals/computer/i94rbac%28org%29.pdf).
As you will see I separated my implementation in two related Interfaces the Session and the Query. The session provides all roles, permissions and user information, so one may query it later via the `Query` object.

I also separated the implementation in two concepts of roles, which are "normal" roles (via `SimpleRbacSession`) and parameterised roles (via `SpecializedRbacSession`). 
In "normal" roles, one simply states that the user have it. In the parameterised roles one states that user have a role for one specific resource. Consider the following examples:

All **teachers** may **lecture** a lesson. Here the role would be **teachers** and the action would be **lecture**. This is a "normal" role

All **teachers of a subject** can **publish** the exam results of that subject in college platform. In this case you need to provide **which subject** that is taught by the Teacher. This is a parameterized role because one needs to provide the resource subject.

Please note that none of either implementations have a role hierarchy support (yet).

This code block contains all interfaces and some delegate definitions as well.

```
public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user, object resource);
public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user, object resource);
public delegate bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, object resource);

public interface IRbacSession
{
   IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> UserRoles { get; }
   IEnumerable<Role> RolePermissions { get; }
   IRbacQuery Query { get; }
   void AddPermission(string roleName, string action);
   void UserIsInRoleIf(string role, Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate);
}


public interface ISpecializedRbacSession : IRbacSession
{
   IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> UserRolesForType { get; }
   IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> UserPermissions { get; }
   new ISpecializedRbacQuery Query { get; }
   void AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(string role, IsUserInRole predicate);
   void AddPermission<T>(string roleName, string action);
}
public interface IRbacQuery
{
   IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user);
   IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user); 
   bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, string role);
   bool IsUserAbleTo(IPrincipal user, string action);
   IEnumerable<string> GetRolePermissions(string roleName);
   bool IsRoleAbleTo(string roleName, string action);
}

public interface ISpecializedRbacQuery : IRbacQuery
{
   IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource);
   IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource); 
   bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource);
   bool IsUserAbleTo<T>(IPrincipal user, string action, T resource);
}
```

The following code block contains some utilitary methods used on the implementation.

```
public class DoubleKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V>: Dictionary<K1, IDictionary<K2, V>>
{
   private IEqualityComparer<K2> keyComparer; 
   public DoubleKeyDictionary(IEqualityComparer<K1> key1Comparer, IEqualityComparer<K2> key2Comparer):base(key1Comparer)
   {
       this.keyComparer = key2Comparer;
   }
   public DoubleKeyDictionary() { } 
   public V this[K1 key1,K2 key2]
   {
       get { return this[key1][key2]; }
       set
       {
           this[key1][key2] = value;
       }
   }

   public void Add(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v)
   {
       if (this[k1] == null)
       {
           this[k1] = new Dictionary<K2, V>(keyComparer);
       }
       this[k1].Add(k2, v);
   }
}

public static class Utils{
    public static V TryGetOrValue<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V value) where V : class
    {
        V ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret ?? value;
        return value;
    }

    public static V? TryGetOrValue<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V?> dictionary, K key, V? value) where V : struct
    {
        V? ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret ?? value;
        return value;
    }

    public static V TryGetOrAdd<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V value) where V : class
    {
        V ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret ?? value;
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return value;
    }

    public static V TryGetOrEmpty<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key) where V : class
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetOrValue(key, null);
    }

    public static V? TryGetOrEmpty<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V?> dictionary, K key) where V : struct
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetOrValue(key, null);
    }

    public static V Memorize<V>(this Func<V> eval) where V : class
    {
        V v = null;
        return new Func<V>(() => v ?? (v = eval()))();
    }
}
```

This is the impelemtantion of the non specialized RBAC version:

**Edit**: I forgot to include the `Role` class

```
public class Role
{
   public Role(string name)
   {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Actions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
   }
   public string Name { get; private set; }

   public ICollection<string> Actions { get; private set; }
}

public class SimpleRbacQuery : IRbacQuery
{
   protected readonly IRbacSession session;

   public SimpleRbacQuery(IRbacSession session)
   {
       this.session = session;
   }

   public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user)
   {
       return session.UserRoles
           .Where(role => role.Value(user))
           .Select(role => role.Key);
   }

   public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user)
   {
       return GetUserRoles(user).SelectMany(GetRolePermissions);
   }

   public virtual bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, string role)
   {
       var userRole = session.UserRoles.TryGetOrEmpty(role);
       if (userRole == null)
       {
           throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("The roleName {0} is not defined", role));
       }
       return userRole(user);
   }

   public bool IsUserAbleTo(IPrincipal principal, string action)
   {
       return GetUserPermissions(principal).Contains(action);
   }

   public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetRolePermissions(string roleName)
   {
       Role role = session.RolePermissions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
       if (role == null)
       {
           return role.Actions;
       }
       return new string[0];
   }

   public virtual bool IsRoleAbleTo(string roleName, string action)
   {
       return GetRolePermissions(roleName).Contains(action);
   }
}

public class SimpleRbacSession : IRbacSession
{
   private readonly IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> userRoles;
   private readonly ICollection<Role> rolePermissions;
   public IRbacQuery Query
   {
       get { return Utils.Memorize(() => new SimpleRbacQuery(this)); }
   }
   public SimpleRbacSession()
   {
       userRoles = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>>();
       rolePermissions = new HashSet<Role>();
   }

   IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> IRbacSession.UserRoles
   {
       get
       {
           return userRoles;
       }
   }

   IEnumerable<Role> IRbacSession.RolePermissions
   {
       get
       {
           return rolePermissions;
       }
   }

   public void AddPermission(string roleName, string action)
   {
       Role role = rolePermissions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
       if (role == null)
       {
           role = new Role(roleName);
       }
       role.Actions.Add(action);
   }

   public void UserIsInRoleIf(string role, Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate)
   {
       userRoles.Add(role, predicate);
   }
}
```

And the implementation of specialized version:

```
public class SpecializedRbacQuery : SimpleRbacQuery, ISpecializedRbacQuery
{ 
   public SpecializedRbacQuery(ISpecializedRbacSession session) : base(session)
   {

   }

   private ISpecializedRbacSession Session
   {
       get { return (ISpecializedRbacSession)session; }
   }

   public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource)
   {
       var userRoles = Session.UserRolesForType.TryGetOrEmpty(typeof (T));
       if (userRoles == null)
       {
           return new string[0];
       }
       return userRoles(user, resource);
   }

   public virtual bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource)
   {
       return GetUserRoles(user, resource).Contains(role);
   }

   public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource)
   {
       if (!Session.UserPermissions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
       {
           return new string[0];
       }
       return Session.UserPermissions[typeof(T)](user, resource);
   }

   public virtual bool IsUserAbleTo<T>(IPrincipal user, string action, T resource)
   {
       return GetUserPermissions(user, resource).Contains(action);
   }
}
public class SpecializedRbacSession : SimpleRbacSession, ISpecializedRbacSession
{
   private class MyQuery : SpecializedRbacQuery
   {
       public MyQuery(SpecializedRbacSession session)
           : base(session)
       {
       }

       private SpecializedRbacSession Session
       {
           get { return (SpecializedRbacSession)session; }
       }

       public override bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource)
       {
           var rolesForType = Session.roleAssignment.TryGetOrEmpty(typeof(T));
           if (rolesForType == null)
           {
               return false;
           }
           var assignment = rolesForType.TryGetOrEmpty(role);
           if (assignment == null)
           {
               return false;
           }
           return assignment(user, resource);
       }
   }
   private readonly IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, IsUserInRole>> roleAssignment =
       new DoubleKeyDictionary<Type, string, IsUserInRole>(null, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

   private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Role>> permissionAssignment = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Role>>();
   IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> ISpecializedRbacSession.UserRolesForType
   {
       get { return GetUserRolesFromAssignment(); }
   }

   IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> ISpecializedRbacSession.UserPermissions
   {
       get
       {
           return GetUserPermissionsFromAssignment();
       }
   }

   public IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, IsUserInRole>> RoleAssignment
   {
       get { return roleAssignment; }
   }

   public void AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(string role, IsUserInRole predicate)
   {
       IDictionary<string, IsUserInRole> roleAssign;
       if (!roleAssignment.ContainsKey(typeof (T)))
       {
           roleAssign = new Dictionary<string, IsUserInRole>();
           roleAssignment.Add(typeof (T), roleAssign);
       }
       else
       {
           roleAssign = roleAssignment[typeof (T)];
       }
       roleAssign.Add(role, predicate);
   }

   public void AddPermission<T>(string roleName, string action)
   {
       ICollection<Role> roles = permissionAssignment.TryGetOrAdd(typeof (T), new HashSet<Role>());
       Role role = roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == action);
       if (role != null)
       {
           role.Actions.Add(action);
       }
       else
       {
           role = new Role(roleName);
           role.Actions.Add(action);
           roles.Add(role);
       }
   }

   private IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> GetUserPermissionsFromAssignment()
   {
       IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> userPermissions = new Dictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions>();
       IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> userRole = GetUserRolesFromAssignment();
       foreach (var permission in permissionAssignment)
       {
           var permissionContext = permission;
           GetUserPermissions getUserPermissions = (user, resource) =>
           {
               //for every roleName that user have check their permissions
               return userRole[permissionContext.Key](user, resource)
                       .SelectMany(role => permissionContext.Value.SelectMany(r => r.Actions));
           };
           userPermissions.Add(permission.Key, getUserPermissions);
       }
       return userPermissions;
   }

   private IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> GetUserRolesFromAssignment()
   {
       IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> userRoles = new Dictionary<Type, GetUserRoles>();
       foreach (var assignment in roleAssignment)
       {
           var assignmentContext = assignment;
           GetUserRoles getUserRoles = (user, resource) =>
           {
               return assignmentContext.Value
                   .Where(e => e.Value(user, resource))
                   .Select(e => e.Key);
           };
           userRoles.Add(assignment.Key, getUserRoles);
       }
       return userRoles;
   }

   public new ISpecializedRbacQuery Query
   {
       get
       {
           return Utils.Memorize(() => new SpecializedRbacQuery(this));
       }
   }
}
```

And finally the fluent API for using it:

```
public class Rbac
{
    public Rbac(IRbacSession session)
    {
        User = new User(session);
        What = new What(session);
        Is = new Is(session);
        Do = new Do(session);
        Can = new Can(session);
    }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public What What { get; private set; }
    public Is Is { get; private set; }
    public Do Do { get; private set; }
    public Can Can { get; private set; }

}
public class User
{
    private readonly IRbacSession session;
    internal User(IRbacSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public UserRole Is(string role)
    {
        return new UserRole(session, role);
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public class UserRole
    {
        internal string Role { get; private set; }
        internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
        internal UserRole(IRbacSession session, string role)
        {
            this.Session = session;
            this.Role = role;
        }

        public void If(Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate)
        {
            Session.UserIsInRoleIf(Role, predicate);
        }

        public UserRoleResource<T> Of<T>()
        {
            return new UserRoleResource<T>(this);
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public class UserRoleResource<T>
    {
        private readonly UserRole userRole;

        internal UserRoleResource(UserRole role)
        {
            this.userRole = role;
        }
        public void If(IsUserInRole predicate)
        {
            ISpecializedRbacSession session = userRole.Session as ISpecializedRbacSession;
            if (session == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            session.AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(userRole.Role, predicate);
        }
    }

}

public class What
{
    internal What(IRbacSession session)
    {
        Can = new _Can(session);
    }

    public _Can Can { get; private set; }

    public class _Can
    {
        internal _Can(IRbacSession session)
        {
            Role = new _Role(session);

        }
        public _Role Role { get; private set; }
        public class _Role
        {
            private readonly IRbacSession session;
            internal _Role(IRbacSession session)
            {
                this.session = session;
            }
            public IEnumerable<string> Do(string role)
            {
                return session.Query.GetRolePermissions(role);
            } 
        }
        public _User User { get; private set; }
        public class _User
        {
            private readonly IRbacSession session;
            internal _User(IRbacSession session)
            {
                this.session = session;
            }
            public IEnumerable<string> Do(IPrincipal principal)
            {
                return session.Query.GetUserPermissions(principal);
            }
        }    
    }

}

public class Is
{
    private readonly IRbacSession session;
    internal Is(IRbacSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public Principal User(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return new Principal(session, principal);
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public class Principal
    {
        internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
        internal IPrincipal User { get; private set; }
        internal Principal(IRbacSession session, IPrincipal user)
        {
            this.Session = session;
            this.User = user;
        }
        public UserRole A(string role)
        {
            return new UserRole(this, role) { Result = Session.Query.IsUserInRole(User, role) };
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class UserRole
        {
            private readonly Principal principal;
            private readonly string role;
            internal UserRole(Principal principal, string role)
            {
                this.principal = principal;
                this.role = role;
            }
            public bool Result { get; set; }

            public bool Of<T>(T resource)
            {
                ISpecializedRbacSession session = principal.Session as ISpecializedRbacSession;
                if (session == null)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                Result = session.Query.IsUserInRole(principal.User, role, resource);
                return Result;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Do
{
    private readonly IRbacSession session;
    internal Do(IRbacSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public _Action A(string name)
    {
        return new _Action(session, name);
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public class _Action
    {
        internal string Action { get; private set; }
        internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }

        internal _Action(IRbacSession session, string action)
        {
            this.Session = session;
            this.Action = action;
        }

        public void Requires(string role)
        {
            Session.AddPermission(role, Action);
        }

        public ActionRequirements<T> Of<T>()
        {
            return new ActionRequirements<T>(this);
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class ActionRequirements<T>
        {
            private readonly _Action action;

            internal ActionRequirements(_Action action)
            {
                this.action = action;
            }

            public void Requires(string role)
            {
                ISpecializedRbacSession session = action.Session as ISpecializedRbacSession;
                if (session == null)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                session.AddPermission<T>(role, action.Action);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Can
{
    private readonly IRbacSession session;
    internal Can(IRbacSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public UserAction User(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return new UserAction(session, principal);
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public class UserAction
    {
        internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
        internal IPrincipal Principal { get; private set; }
        internal UserAction(IRbacSession session, IPrincipal principal)
        {
            this.Session = session;
            this.Principal = principal;
        }

        public ActionResource Do(string action)
        {
            return new ActionResource(this, action){Result = Session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(Principal, action)};
        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class ActionResource
        {
            private readonly UserAction userAction;
            private readonly string action;
            internal ActionResource(UserAction userAction, string action)
            {
                this.userAction = userAction;
                this.action = action;
            }

            public bool Result { get; set; }

            public bool The<T>(T resource)
            {
                ISpecializedRbacSession session = userAction.Session as ISpecializedRbacSession;
                if (session == null)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                Result = session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(userAction.Principal, action, resource);
                return Result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for any suggestions of improvements, either on the fluent API or the implementation itself. I am also looking for any violations of the concept of RBAC in this implementation.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the asp.net identity claims stuff? It seems capable of achieving a lot of these things and is fairly simple and standardized.

Comment: I'll be looking into that. The only mechanism I had contact so far in .NET about authorization/authentication is Role provider and Membership provider. But I would like a review on this code anyway.

Comment: I realize the post is long enough as is, but it would be nice if you could add a small snippet showing how the fluent API is consumed in some example/test code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user, object resource);
> public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user, object resource);
> public delegate bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, object resource);
> ```

I seldom create new delegate types, I tend to use `Action` and `Func` delegates instead, but I like how it makes an enjoyable read, especially here:

> ```
> IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> UserRolesForType { get; }
> IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> UserPermissions { get; }
> ```

Why is the former called `UserRolesForType`? Then why isn't the latter called `UserPermissionsForType`? Consistency is your friend!

---

We could consider the distinction between "normal" and "parameterized" queries as superfluous:

```
public interface IRbacQuery
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user);
    IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource);

    IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user); 
    IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource); 

    bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, string role);
    bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource);

    bool IsUserAbleTo(IPrincipal user, string action);
    bool IsUserAbleTo<T>(IPrincipal user, string action, T resource);

    IEnumerable<string> GetRolePermissions(string roleName);
    bool IsRoleAbleTo(string roleName, string action);
}
```

The implementating types would expose both variants:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user)
{
    return session.UserRoles
                  .Where(role => role.Value(user))
                  .Select(role => role.Key);
}

public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource)
{
    var userRoles = session.UserRolesForType.TryGetOrEmpty(typeof (T));
    if (userRoles == null)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
    return userRoles(user, resource);
}
```

The generic overload would no longer need to cast `session` into an `ISpecializedRbacSession` (assuming `GetRolesForType` becomes a member of `IRbacSession`), and it seems to me the client code would get simpler... unless you already only expose the "specialized" interface, so the client code *already sees both overloads*?

---

The nesting of the types in the last code block is interesting:

- `Rbac`
- `User`

  - `UserRole`
  - `UserRoleResource<T>`
- `What`

  - `_Can`

    - `_Role`
    - `_User`
- `Is`

  - `Principal`

    - `UserRole`
- `Do`

  - `_Action`

    - `ActionRequirements<T>`
- `Can`

  - `UserAction`

    - `ActionResource`

I'd have to spend a great deal of time on this code to understand the presence of an `_` underscore prefix on *some* of the *public classes* you have here, and why `User`, `What`, `Is`, `Do` and `Can` aren't themselves nested under `Rbac`, because there's *strong coupling* going on here:

> ```
> public Rbac(IRbacSession session)
> {
>     User = new User(session);
>     What = new What(session);
>     Is = new Is(session);
>     Do = new Do(session);
>     Can = new Can(session);
> }
> ```

I like the constructor-injected `session` though.

---

As for the implementations themselves, I find the dictionary assignations could use some `var`:

> ```
> IDictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions> userPermissions = new Dictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions>();
> ```

Compare to:

```
var userPermissions = new Dictionary<Type, GetUserPermissions>();
```

---

In the same method, seeing this line:

```
foreach (var permission in permissionAssignment)
```

Made me scroll all the way up to this declaration:

```
private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Role>> permissionAssignment = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Role>>();
```

If `permissionAssignment` had been called `_permissionAssignment`, I would have known at a glance that it was a private field, ...but that's just me being used to that underscore and being a bit nitpicky, the code looks good, really.

Comment: In my first implementation I also used Func, but I realized that the code could become more readable and had more meaning if I created delegates. I separated the RBAC from specialized rbac because these are different versions of RBAC Model and I just tried to map that on my code. I usually like to deny the usage of var but I guess that's a situation that is ok to use it. The only convention that I do not respect from c# is exactly the field naming convention, I perhaps should use ``this`` every time I refer to a field.