# Fluent API of a RBAC implementation - follow-up

Tags: c#, authorization

[In the past I posted a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52155/fluent-api-of-a-role-based-access-control-implementation) that tried to implement a nice API to support RBAC authorization to resources. And due to the epoch and probably to the bount it was moderatly well received by the community. Althought even I myself can now spot how fundamentally flawed was that question due to the following reasons:

- The code was not properly tested by myself and the result was, of course, very bugy code
- I didn't provide usage scenarios so you couldn't spot the usefulness of my implementation and why is it so good (or bad)

Having said that I applied the suggestions made by Mat, tested my code, removed many unnecessary redundant code and now I would like to get another review on the implementation.

The interfaces:

```
public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user, object resource);
public delegate IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user, object resource);
public delegate bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, object resource);

public interface IRbacSession
{
    IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> UserRoles { get; }
    IEnumerable<Role> RolePermissions { get; }
    IRbacQuery Query { get; }
    void AddPermission(string roleName, string action);
    void UserIsInRoleIf(string role, Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate);
    IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> UserRolesForType { get; }
    void AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(string role, IsUserInRole predicate);
}

public interface IRbacQuery
{
    bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, string role);
    bool IsUserAbleTo(IPrincipal user, string action);
    bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource);
    bool IsUserAbleTo<T>(IPrincipal user, string action, T resource);
}
```

The query implementation

```
public class RbacQuery : IRbacQuery
{
    protected readonly IRbacSession _session;

    public RbacQuery(IRbacSession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource)
    {
        var userRoles = _session.UserRolesForType.TryGetOrEmpty(typeof(T));
        if (userRoles == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
        return userRoles(user, resource);
    }

    public virtual bool IsUserInRole<T>(IPrincipal user, string role, T resource)
    {
        return user.IsInRole(role) ||
            GetUserRoles(user, resource).Contains(role, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions<T>(IPrincipal user, T resource)
    {
        var userRoles = _session.UserRolesForType.TryGetOrEmpty(typeof(T));
        if (userRoles == null)
        {
            return GetUserPermissions(user);
        }
        return userRoles(user, resource).Union(GetUserPermissions(user));
    }

    public virtual bool IsUserAbleTo<T>(IPrincipal user, string action, T resource)
    {
        return GetUserRoles(user, resource).Any(r => IsUserInRole(user, r, resource)) ||
        GetUserPermissions(user, resource).Contains(action, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserRoles(IPrincipal user)
    {
        var userRoles = _session.RolePermissions
            .Where(r => user.IsInRole(r.Name))
            .Select(r => r.Name);
        return _session.UserRoles
            .Where(role => role.Value(user))
            .Select(role => role.Key)
            .Union(userRoles);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetUserPermissions(IPrincipal user)
    {
        return GetUserRoles(user).SelectMany(GetRolePermissions);
    }

    public virtual bool IsUserInRole(IPrincipal user, string role)
    {
        if (user.IsInRole(role))
        {
            return true;
        }
        var userRole = _session.UserRoles.TryGetOrEmpty(role);
        bool roleExists = userRole != null ||
            _session.RolePermissions
            .Any(r => r.Name.Equals(role, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (!roleExists)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"The roleName {role} is not defined");
        }
        if (userRole == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return userRole(user);
    }

    public bool IsUserAbleTo(IPrincipal principal, string action)
    {
        return GetUserPermissions(principal).Contains(action, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetRolePermissions(string roleName)
    {
        var role = _session.RolePermissions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
        if (role != null)
        {
            return role.Actions;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

The RBAC session implementation

```
public class RbacSession : IRbacSession
{
    protected readonly IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> _userRoles;
    protected readonly ICollection<Role> _rolePermissions;
    private RbacQuery _query;
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, IsUserInRole>> _roleAssignment =
        new Dictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, IsUserInRole>>();
    public IRbacQuery Query
    {
        get
        {
            if (_query != null)
            {
                return _query;
            }
            return _query = new RbacQuery(this);
        }
    }
    public RbacSession()
    {
        _userRoles = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>>();
        _rolePermissions = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    IDictionary<string, Predicate<IPrincipal>> IRbacSession.UserRoles
    {
        get
        {
            return _userRoles;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<Role> IRbacSession.RolePermissions
    {
        get
        {
            return _rolePermissions;
        }
    }

    public void AddPermission(string roleName, string action)
    {
        var role = _rolePermissions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new Role(roleName);
            _rolePermissions.Add(role);
        }
        role.Actions.Add(action);
    }

    public void UserIsInRoleIf(string role, Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate)
    {
        _userRoles.Add(role, predicate);
    }

    IDictionary<Type, GetUserRoles> IRbacSession.UserRolesForType
    {
        get
        {
            var userRoles = new Dictionary<Type, GetUserRoles>();
            foreach (var assignment in _roleAssignment)
            {
                var assignmentContext = assignment;
                GetUserRoles getUserRoles = (user, resource) =>
                {
                    return assignmentContext.Value
                        .Where(e => e.Value(user, resource))
                        .Select(e => e.Key);
                };
                userRoles.Add(assignment.Key, getUserRoles);
            }
            return userRoles;
        }
    }

    public void AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(string role, IsUserInRole predicate)
    {
        var roleAssign = _roleAssignment.TryGetOrAdd(typeof(T), new Dictionary<string, IsUserInRole>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        roleAssign.Add(role, predicate);
    }
}
```

Utility methods (I do not require a review on those, but feel free to comment if you have something to say about them)

```
public static class DictionaryUtils
{
    public static V TryGetOrValue<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V value)
    {
        V ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret;
        return value;
    }

    public static V TryGetOrEmpty<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key)
    {
        V ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret;
        return default(V);
    }

    public static V TryGetOrAdd<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V value)
    {
        V ret;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
            return ret;
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return value;
    }

    public static V AddOrUpdate<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V value, Func<V, V> newValue)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return dictionary[key] = newValue(dictionary[key]);
        }
        return dictionary[key] = value;
    }
}
```

The fluent API (instead of doing review on this API you may instead prefer to discuss if it was a good, or a bad decision)

```
public class Rbac
{
    public class _User
    {
        private readonly IRbacSession _session;
        internal _User(IRbacSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
        public UserRole Is(string role)
        {
            return new UserRole(_session, role);
        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class UserRole
        {
            internal string Role { get; private set; }
            internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
            internal UserRole(IRbacSession session, string role)
            {
                Session = session;
                Role = role;
            }

            public void If(Predicate<IPrincipal> predicate)
            {
                Session.UserIsInRoleIf(Role, predicate);
            }

            public UserRoleResource<T> Of<T>()
            {
                var session = Session;
                return new UserRoleResource<T>(this);
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class UserRoleResource<T>
        {
            private readonly UserRole _userRole;

            internal UserRoleResource(UserRole role)
            {
                _userRole = role;
            }
            public void If(Func<IPrincipal, T, bool> pred)
            {
                var session = _userRole.Session;
                if (session == null)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                session.AddUserRoleForTypeIf<T>(_userRole.Role, (user, resource) => pred(user, (T)resource));
            }
        }

    }

    public class _Is
    {
        private readonly IRbacSession _session;
        internal _Is(IRbacSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
        public Principal User(IPrincipal principal)
        {
            return new Principal(_session, principal);
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class Principal
        {
            internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
            internal IPrincipal User { get; private set; }
            internal Principal(IRbacSession session, IPrincipal user)
            {
                Session = session;
                User = user;
            }
            public UserRole A(string role)
            {
                return new UserRole(this, role) { Result = Session.Query.IsUserInRole(User, role) };
            }

            [Browsable(false)]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public class UserRole
            {
                private readonly Principal _principal;
                private readonly string _role;
                internal UserRole(Principal principal, string role)
                {
                    _principal = principal;
                    _role = role;
                }
                public bool Result { get; set; }

                public bool Of<T>(T resource)
                {
                    var session = _principal.Session;
                    Result = session.Query.IsUserInRole(_principal.User, _role, resource);
                    return Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class _Do
    {
        private readonly IRbacSession _session;
        internal _Do(IRbacSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
        public _Action A(string name)
        {
            return new _Action(_session, name);
        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class _Action
        {
            internal string Action { get; private set; }
            internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }

            internal _Action(IRbacSession session, string action)
            {
                Session = session;
                Action = action;
            }

            public void Requires(string role)
            {
                Session.AddPermission(role, Action);
            }

        }
    }

    public class _Can
    {
        private readonly IRbacSession _session;
        internal _Can(IRbacSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
        public UserAction User(IPrincipal principal = null)
        {
            return new UserAction(_session, principal ?? Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public class UserAction
        {
            internal IRbacSession Session { get; private set; }
            internal IPrincipal Principal { get; private set; }
            internal UserAction(IRbacSession session, IPrincipal principal)
            {
                Session = session;
                Principal = principal;
            }

            public ActionResource Do(string action)
            {
                return new ActionResource(this, action)
                {
                    Result = Session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(Principal, action)
                };
            }
            [Browsable(false)]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public class ActionResource
            {
                private readonly UserAction _userAction;
                private readonly string _action;
                internal ActionResource(UserAction userAction, string action)
                {
                    _userAction = userAction;
                    _action = action;
                }

                public bool Result { get; set; }

                public bool The<T>(T resource)
                {
                    var session = _userAction.Session;
                    Result = session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(_userAction.Principal, _action, resource);
                    return Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Rbac(IRbacSession session)
    {
        User = new _User(session);
        Is = new _Is(session);
        Do = new _Do(session);
        Can = new _Can(session);
    }
    public _User User { get; private set; }
    public _Is Is { get; private set; }
    public _Do Do { get; private set; }
    public _Can Can { get; private set; }
}
```

Tests

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestRbac
{
    public class Principal : IPrincipal, IIdentity
    {
        private readonly HashSet<string> _roles = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        public IIdentity Identity
        {
            get
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        public ICollection<string> Roles { get { return _roles; } }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return _roles.Contains(role);
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, IPrincipal> _users;
    private Rbac _rbac;
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _users = new Dictionary<string, IPrincipal>();
        _users.Add("owner", new Principal
        {
            Roles = { "owner", "member", "user" }
        });
        _users.Add("member", new Principal
        {
            Roles = { "member", "user" }
        });
        _users.Add("user", new Principal
        {
            Roles = { "user" }
        });
        _users.Add("evaluator", new Principal
        {
            Roles = { "evaluator" }
        });
        _users.Add("teacher", new Principal
        {
            Roles = { "teacher" }
        });
        _users.Add("Bob", new Principal
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Roles = { "owner" }
        });

        _rbac = new Rbac(new RbacSession());
        _rbac.Do.A("Delete").Requires("owner");
        _rbac.Do.A("Transfer").Requires("owner");
        _rbac.Do.A("Comment").Requires("member");
        _rbac.Do.A("Create").Requires("member");
        _rbac.Do.A("Read").Requires("user");
        _rbac.Do.A("Maintnance").Requires("mantainer");
        _rbac.User.Is("mantainer").If(u => u.Identity.Name == "Bob");

        _rbac.Do.A("Evaluation").Requires("Evaluator");
        _rbac.Do.A("Grading").Requires("Teacher");
        _rbac.User.Is("Teacher").Of<string>().If((user, resource) => resource=="Hello world");
    }


    [Test]
    public void TestHasRole()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["owner"]).A("owner").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["member"]).A("Member").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["member"]).A("User").Result);
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Is.User(_users["member"]).A("owner").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["user"]).A("user").Result);
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Is.User(_users["user"]).A("member").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["Bob"]).A("mantainer").Result);

        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["teacher"]).A("Teacher").Of("the exam"));
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Is.User(_users["user"]).A("teacher").Of("the exam"));
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Is.User(_users["user"]).A("Teacher").Of("Hello world"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCanDo()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["owner"]).Do("Delete").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["owner"]).Do("transfer").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["owner"]).Do("comment").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["owner"]).Do("Create").Result);
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Can.User(_users["owner"]).Do("Maintnance").Result);

        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["member"]).Do("Create").Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["member"]).Do("read").Result);

        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["user"]).Do("read").Result);
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Can.User(_users["user"]).Do("Delete").Result);
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Can.User(_users["user"]).Do("transfer").Result);

        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["Bob"]).Do("Maintnance").Result);

        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["evaluator"]).Do("Evaluation").The("anything :p"));
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["evaluator"]).Do("Evaluation").The(1));
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["teacher"]).Do("grading").The("the exam"));
        Assert.IsTrue(_rbac.Can.User(_users["user"]).Do("grading").The("Hello world"));
        Assert.IsFalse(_rbac.Can.User(_users["user"]).Do("grading").The("protected resource to other user"));
    }
}
```

Comment: code on [github](https://github.com/brunoss/Toolbox/tree/master/Toolbox.Rbac)

Comment: @Mat'sMug maybe you are able to spend some time on this one again :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know,

I *love* fluent interfaces.

though I feel many misconstrue their purpose.

some examples I see try to make their code a 'natural language'. but That is not the point, the point is to decrease complexity and aid understanding, often most easily done via Natural language.

I can't help but feel the above has crossed the threshold into requiring more time to learn than a standard composition. If i was dead set on fluent I would sacrifice a small amount of natural sentence structure for brevity:

```
 _users["owner"].Can("read").On(_rbac)
```

cuts 48 characters to 38 and keeps the intent clear. It also follows the consistent intention of the user of this code of asking a question about the article, in this case is the current user.

**but why stop there?**

why not make a DSL and eval and compile and evaluate your own custom language:

```
     string query = "Can *owner* Do *Delete*";
     if(eval(query)){}
```

why? ... because that is insane.

---

at the end of the day, ask yourself if you would genuinely prefer to parse the syntax:

```
 var hasRole = _rbac.Is.User(_users["Bob"]).A("Maintainer").Result
```

or the slightly more verbose:

```
 var user = _users["Bob"];
 var hasRole = user.HasRole("Maintainer",_schoolAdminSystem);
```

---

Take linq as an example. it takes a small bit more time to get used to than a system like this which has a more *Sentence.Styled.Structure* but it is a nice hybrid of english and code.

any time i see a fluent system with an Is or a Has, I have to wonder who the target audience is/ what is the objective

### your team?

they understand code syntax, they don't need so much of a hand that it needs to be near english.

### business users

to them code is code, they will be scared of a.sentence.like.this just as much as standard code.

### the team taking over?

would you find it easy to add a feature to a system that is composed of a deeply nested structure of sub classes to enforce a sentence shape or to add an additional extension method and get 75% there?

### Yourself?

well, having written the code base you presumably know it, often times a fluent interface is more verbose and so takes you longer, does it add enough value to yourself to warrant the additional workload?

---

So in summary i am not saying it isn't pretty cool, I can't really fault it as is designed, but as this is a code *review*, traditionally defined as an evaluation I have to evaluate the actual pragmatic value.

and I don't see it.

you can go fluent....er than code without architecting an entire supporting structure and creating a number of dangling hard to ducky-problem solve/ducky debug classes like _is.

---

## TL;DR

when approaching designing a fluent interface I would err on the side of simplicity, having more tailored and specific functions like

```
 user.IsAllowedTo("organize")
 role.ContainsUsers("Mark","Mary")
 user.CanModify().Resource(StudentList);
```

may not be as all powerful but creating them when you need them is preferable to a god system that is hard to understand and edit, while not adding a lot more in terms of readability and take far longer to design and implement.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very very much to give me an explanation how a fluent API should be like. I wasn't really expecting that. Learned a lot!