# Rbac Principal with Binding support

Tags: c#, authentication

I've been maintaining a `Rbac` helper for some time now. My goal is to provide an easy way to tell the following:

- When does an user have a role
- What can a user do (with those roles)
- Which users have which role in which resources

And I'm pretty happy with my result so far, I can do the following:

```
var rbac = new RbacSession();
rbac.AddPermission("owner", "Delete");
rbac.UserIsInRoleIf("mantainer", u => u.Identity.Name == "Bob");
rbac.AddUserRoleForTypeIf<string>("Teacher", (user, resource) => resource == "Hello world");
```

[I have been told](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116822/fluent-api-of-a-rbac-implementation-follow-up) to get rid of my fluent interface because all of it was wrong.

And my thought was, well yeah... But hey, wouldn't it be really cool if I could support properties to check if a `user` has a role? If I did I could also support easy binding to `WPF` Applications. Here follows the implementation

```
public class RbacPrincipal : IPrincipal, IIdentity
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public class CanDoAction
    {
        private readonly RbacPrincipal _principal;
        public CanDoAction(RbacPrincipal principal)
        {
            _principal = principal;
        }

        public bool this[string action]
        {
            get
            {
                return _principal._session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(_principal, action);
            }
        }

        public bool this[string action, object resource]
        {
            get
            {
                return _principal._session.Query.IsUserAbleTo(_principal, action, resource);
            }
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public class IsUserInRole
    {
        private readonly RbacPrincipal _principal;

        public IsUserInRole(RbacPrincipal principal)
        {
            _principal = principal;
        }

        public bool this[string role]
        {
            get
            {
                return _principal._session.Query.IsUserInRole(_principal, role);
            }
        }

        public bool this[string role, object resource]
        {
            get
            {
                return _principal._session.Query.IsUserInRole(_principal, role, resource);
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly IPrincipal _principal;
    private readonly IRbacSession _session;
    public RbacPrincipal(IPrincipal principal, IRbacSession session)
    {
        _principal = principal;
        _session = session;
        CanDo = new CanDoAction(this);
        Is = new IsUserInRole(this);
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        //check role on the decorated principal se we avoid stackoverflow
        return _session.Query.IsUserInRole(_principal, role);
    }

    public CanDoAction CanDo { get; private set; }
    public IsUserInRole Is { get; private set; }

    IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity { get { return _principal.Identity; } }
    public string Name { get { return _principal.Identity.Name; } }
    public string AuthenticationType { get { return _principal.Identity.AuthenticationType; } }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get { return _principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; } }
}
```

And an example of the usage of it

```
var owner = new RbacPrincipal(new Principal
{
    Roles = { "owner", "member", "user" }
}, rbac);
Assert.IsTrue(owner.Is["owner"]);
Assert.IsTrue(owner.Is["member"]);
Assert.IsTrue(owner.CanDo["Delete"]);
```

[I leave the link to full test class on repo here](https://github.com/brunoss/Toolbox/blob/master/ToolBox.Test/TestRbac.cs)

Now I have one limitation if I use bindings with this. The resources cannot be anything but strings, but at least, and most important I can let you check a role of a user with a binding `Is[owner]`.

Is this it? Did I finally reach the "yayness"?

Comment: I don't understand, why is the syntax `owner.Is["owner"]` instead of `owner.Is("owner")` or maybe even better `owner.IsInRole("owner")`?

Comment: @svick If it were a method it couldn't be binded, at least not without help from converters. And notice that I also support `owner.IsInRole("owner")`